# Magento 2 UPSELL product list showing same price as of Product

Tags: magento2, products, up-sells, manage-stock

I'm facing an issue with **Magento 2.1 UPSELL PRODUCT LISTING**. All the upsell products are showing same price as that of the PRODUCT price. In back-end I have set **Manage Stock** as **NO** as I don't need to managing stock at all. The issue only related to few products as others are loading fine.

How I can resolve the issue?, anyone knows please help me.

Attaching the back-end upsell product configuration screen and front-end view.
[image: FRONT-END VIEW]

[image: BACK-END VIEW]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below solution..

```
/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml
```

Look for below line in the above file

```
var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');
```

To

```
var priceBoxes = $('.product-info-price [data-role=priceBox]');
```

This worked for me. It selects only product `priceBox` in `priceBoxes` rather than all `priceBoxs` on the page.

Comment: Its working, In my case the theme has been override the Module, so I did the modification in theme itself. Thankyou @Subin Chandran

Comment: how to choose price box for upsell product